# JavaFX: Populating TableView with data from different classes

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am creating an application that have different classes such as `User`, `Product`, `Donor` and `Car`. Each of these classes stores relevant information to be shown in a JavaFX `TableView` – the `User` class having a `String name` and `int userID` for instance.

I collect all of these in a class called `Data` that takes the above mentioned classes and stores them. I end up with an `ArrayList<Data>` where each index stores the four classes above.

If I make an `ObservableArrayList` based on the `ArrayList<Data>` how do I retrieve the information from each class stored in the `Data` class? I am following [Oracle's own tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm), but it only accounts for a case where you want to store a single class' information.

Thanks!

Comment: One approach would be to have a different `TableView` for each data type, and switch the table views in and out of the scene graph (instead of using a single table view, and replacing its data, which I think is what you're proposing in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you mention uses a [PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html).  That is not applicable here as that only introspects on a given class, but if you look at the documentation for that class it includes the following long form:

```
TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
     public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> p) {
         // p.getValue() returns the Person instance for a particular TableView row
         return p.getValue().firstNameProperty();
     }
  });
}
```

So you can use the same concept with your data class to retrieve the appropriate field from the user object of the data object:

```
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Data, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
     public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Data, String> data) {
         // data.getValue() returns the Data instance for a particular TableView row
         return data.getValue().getUser().firstNameProperty();
     }
  });
}
```

Some of the ugliness can be removed if you use Java 8 lambdas.

If your user object doesn't have property accessors for the values, but only getters, you can wrap the result in a ReadOnlyObjectWrapper as described in the PropertyValueFactory documentation:

```
return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(data.getValue().getUser().getFirstName());
```

This is fine if your table is not editable and you don't want the table data to change automatically If the underlying field changes, otherwise the property accessor based method is preferred.